# sum filtered column in table Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write code that takes filtered criterium in column H (Associated work flow) from table below and than sums column G (Celková výše výnosu v EUR) according to columns C (Outbound/Inbound) and I (Úspěšně předáno) and place final number to Cell K3 by pressing button (Spustit).
I think it should work like this, i choose criterium in column H, for example Jade&Fountain, it will show me only rows that includes Jade&Fountain, i will press the button, and it will sum only those with Yes in column I + if there is I in column C, it will subtract from the total, if there is O, it will add to the total. Then it will show the total in Cell K3.
I add code i wrote, it should work, but i am not sure in the `Do While Cells(i,2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value <> ""` section. Thanks for any response.

```
Sub While_loop()

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
    i = 3
    x = 0

Do While Cells(i, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value <> ""

    If Cells(i, 9).Value = "Yes" Then

           If Cells(i, 3).Value = "O" Then
           x = x + Cells(i, 7).Value
           End If

           If Cells(i, 3).Value = "I" Then
           x = x - Cells(i, 7).Value
           End If

    End If
    i = i + 1

Loop

Cells(2, 12).Value = x

End Sub
```

Table i am refering to

[image]

Comment: WElcome to SO. This sound like you may benefit from using [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b). VBA versión of this function is `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without VBA if you want to, following this tutorial https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria

Try this function (assuming data in row 3-15), the key is the SUBTOTAL function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C3:C15="O")*(I3:I15="Yes")*(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(G3:G15,ROW(G3:G15)-MIN(ROW(G3:G15)),0,1))))
```

That gives the sum of all visible rows with your 2 criteria. If you want to deduct the I :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C3:C15="O")*(I3:I15="Yes")*(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(G3:G15,ROW(G3:G15)-MIN(ROW(G3:G15)),0,1))))-SUMPRODUCT((C3:C15="I")*(I3:I15="Yes")*(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(G3:G15,ROW(G3:G15)-MIN(ROW(G3:G15)),0,1))))
```